# PHP MySQL Calendar to show data only on that date

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to create a calendar that when I clicked on a specific month day and year. I get to display my table with the data that are on that chosen date?

This is my code which only shows the data from my table "report"

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM report");

echo "<head><style>
table {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}
td, tr, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
}
.page td {
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

.page {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.page a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


</style></head>";
echo "<table class='page'>
<tr>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>FileName</th>
<th>FileType</th>
<th>Date Received</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['agency'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filetype'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='../annual/CAAP/" . $row['filename'] . 
"'>OPEN FILE</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. This a common feature of calendars.

Comment: Can you please help me how to do it, or even a link about it will be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the date somehow in PHP, so either via a form submission or have a fixed date (of today?) set in the script. Then use this date to limit the results in the query to match the date in your PHP script using the where-clause.

The fact that your question is a basic PHP and MySQL question, I assume you don't have a lot of experience in either of them. I would suggest reading up on both of them and learn from the examples used. This is a good resource to learn more about the MySQL where clause:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/